# How to find the creator of a dataset in BigQuery?

Tags: bash, google-bigquery

I am trying to find:

1. who created a dataset in BigQuery
2. and if possible if it was done via GUI or CLI etc.

Currently using the Google Cloud SDK:

1. I am checking against every project my account is linked with, using the Google Cloud SDK.
2. With the following command inside a loop for every project, I get info for the label `userByEmail`.
   Command: `bq show --format=prettyjson ${dataset} | awk /userByEmail/'{gsub ("\"", ""); print proj",",dat",",$2}' proj=${project} dat=${dataset}`

This gives me info about who has access to these datasets, but it's not what I am looking for.

Any ideas on how to get the correct info on an automated fashion?

Comment: I can't find creator info on dataset either. If you have audit logging enabled, you may be able to mine audit log to find out who created it.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have audit logging.

Answer (score 0):

The only place creator information would be exposed is via the [BigQuery audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs).

Even with the audit information at your disposal, the second part of your question (what tool issued the request) is likely to remain ambiguous.